# Google Maps nor clickable neither pannable on Magento Homapage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, magento, google-maps-api-3

I have put google maps on magento website. Google maps appears on homepage, and also markers are displayed. But the problem is the map is nor clickable neither pannable. I cannot click and I cannot pan. But on the property listing page, it is clickable, and also pannable, without any problem.

```
Link to home page (where it doesn't work): http://spacedookie.com/
Link to listing page (where works well): http://spacedookie.com/index.php/villa-1050.html
```

I don't know why it is showing on listing page. I don't want it there. What I want to achieve is to show the map and properties listing on  homepage, but there it is not clickable. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Update**: Thanks to Gerard de Visser. Now I can pan the map, but now the marker is not clickable.

I renamed the div element id from "map_canvas" to "map_canvas_listings" and also removed all other javascript codes that were for google maps, implemented by someone-else on my client's website, and problem is solved. The duplicate codes were conflicting. But now the problem is, when i click the marker, the info window doesn't appear. I have implemented the same google maps on my local host and the info window appears without any issue. What may be the possible problem here?

Comment: console log at your example page is full of errors. And map is half loaded (Chrome).

Comment: what is url of your listing page?

Comment: @Muk I updated the question. Please reply me accordingly if you have solution.

Comment: @AntoJurković what do you mean by half? Half in width or height?

Comment: Only upper half of the map was displayed.

Comment: @AntoJurković in mapOptions, I set the zoom: 4 so only map of USA is displayed, not whole world. Do you mean this? or something else?

Comment: No, only upper part of map is loaded, other space is just empty - grey color.

Comment: @AntoJurković For, it is opening fully, not half. Can you help me why the infoWindow doesn't open when I click the marker? On my localhost, the same google maps code opens infoWindow but on live magento website it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps is embedded twice on your homepage. That causes the error. Make sure to embed it only once.

Comment: Ok, i will folow your instructions, but if you check the source of listing page, there is also embedded twice, then why it is working well on listing page?